# Finding Facebook Business manager account by ID?

Tags: facebook, facebook-business-manager

Facebook Business Manager Account ID is known but the login credentials are unknown. Is there any way or online tool to find the email account behind the FB Business account by ID?
Purpose is to recover the account.

```
ID: 490403301730920
```

Comment: There is no way to do that via API (you would have to have a valid access token _for_ that account to begin with), and I don't see how any external services would get that kind of info either (they are usually based on scraping frontend pages.)